# Valgrind Invalid Read of Size 8 for insertion sort

Tags: c++

I'm trying to executing a really simple code, but I keep getting Valgrind error.

```
double s[4];
double aux;

unsigned int i, j;

for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

  aux = 5.0; // there is actually a function returning a value here

  for(j = i-1; j >= 0 && s[j] > aux; j--) s[j+1] = s[j];
  s[j+1] = aux;
}
```

That's a simple decreasing insertion sort, but I keep getting Segmentation Fault (Invalid read size of 8 on Vaulgrind)

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `i` and `j` are *unsigned* types.  Hence your `j` loop is full of problems:

When `i` is 0:

- the loop starts at `(unsigned)-1` (*i.e.* `UINT_MAX`)
- `j >= 0` is always true
- `s[j]` accesses outside the valid buffer (this is probably what leads to the valgrind error)

In any iteration:

- `j--` will eventually wrap to `UINT_MAX`, if `s[j] > aux` is never false

Simply using signed integers for your array indices, or being more careful with reverse loops that use unsigned indices, should fix your problem.